# Copy AWS Prefix List from one region to other regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-cli, aws-regions

**TL;DR:** Copy AWS Prefix List (PL) from one region to other regions and when main PL is updated, update all copies of that list.

**Long Story:**

Hi, I want to publish my site in multiple regions using AWS and plan on using Cloudflare for Geo based load balancing. However the issue is that I want to restrict SSH / other access of all servers / VPS instances to specific IPs.

One way is to add all my IPs to security groups linked to servers / VPS instances in all regions. Other is to create same Prefix List in all regions and reference that PL in related security group. But both of these techniques make addition / removal of IPs, quite hectic.

Easy way, it seems, is to create Prefix List in main / default region and copy it to all other regions and reference copied PL to related Security Groups in all regions. And when the PL in main / default region gets updated, trigger the copy mechanism again, manually or automatically.

Any suggestions / solutions / references, please.